# div id with same name before the original div

Tags: javascript, jquery

Good morning,
I have a question how do I get an id of div. One more after the initial div.

EX:

```
  <div class="1">
      <div class="2">
         <div class="3">
            <div class="4">
               <div class="up" id="2"> UP </ div> <<- get id here
            </ div>
         </ div>
      </ div>
    </ div>

  <div class="1">
      <div class="2">
         <div class="3">
            <div class="4">
               <div class="up" id="1"> UP </ div> <<- Click
            </ div>
         </ div>
      </ div>
    </ div>
```

I'll be grateful for the help.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Get the `id` attribute of the first `<div>` with class "up" after the second `<div>` with class "up" is clicked?

Comment: Yes, when class is clicked down. Id pick up a class...

Comment: Always pick up the id of the class. When clicked

Comment: `$('.up').attr("id");` ? Your question or requirements are not clear.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming the outer div always has the same class:

```
$('.up').click(function(){
   alert( $(this).closest('.1').prev().find('.up').attr('id') );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        function getId(){
           var allDiv = document.getElementsByTagNames("div");
           for(i=0; i<allDiv.lebgth; i++){
                 for(j=i; j<allDiv.lebgth; j++){
                      if(allDiv[i].className == allDiv[j].className )
                              return allDiv[i].getAttribute("id");
                       }
                  }
                  return "";
        }
```